# How to find Decile in R if the data set has NA values

Tags: r

I am Trying to rank for the data using decile using `r`. Here is the code.

```
X<-c(1,6,2,4,3,5,12,9,8,10,11,7)

NewVar<-cut(X,quantile(X,(0:10)/10),include.lowest=TRUE)

cbind(X,NewVar)

       X NewVar

 [1,]  1      1
 [2,]  6      5
 [3,]  2      1
 [4,]  4      3
 [5,]  3      2
 [6,]  5      4
 [7,] 12     10
 [8,]  9      8
 [9,]  8      7
[10,] 10      9
[11,] 11     10
[12,]  7      6
```

For the above data set it is Giving correct values.

But If the Data set has NA values then it is giving error as shown below.

```
X<-c(1,6,2,4,3,5,12,9,8,10,NA,11,7,NA)

NewVar<-cut(X,quantile(X,(0:10)/10),include.lowest=TRUE, na.rm=FALSE)

error is "Error in quantile.default(X, (0:10)/10) :
missing values and NaN's not allowed if 'na.rm' is FALSE"
```

Comment: add `na.rm = TRUE` as an argument to `quantile()`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic as it was caused by mistyping `na.rm` as `na,rm`.